# How to change the value of a text input after clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid

I am trying to change the value of the text input after I click on the button but when I run my page the text input takes the value immediately without clicking on the button. Like in this case the text input shows "1" without clicking on the button!
What is the problem with this code?

```js
{
    function Button(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    Button.prototype.val = document.getElementById("b").onclick = function() {
         return this.x;
    }

    let button = new Button(1)
    document.getElementById("text").value = button.val();
}
```

Comment: You run `document.getElementById("text").value = button.val();`, invoking it immediately

Comment: so what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

You should have added the changing of value inside `addEventListener` (in your case, it is called immediately) and you don't need to bother with using prototype. Below is a simple example that does the job -

```js
const yourValue = 10;
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',() => document.getElementById('input').value = yourValue)
```

```html
<input id='input'></input>
<button id='btn'>click me</button>
```

Comment: but i wanna use it with a constructor because i want to do multiple buttons and there are multiples values

Comment: You can add multiple event listeners rather than creating multiple buttons. You could also create a function that will take parameter that you can pass to event listener that the function creates

Answer (score 1):

You declare 3 variables: `input`, `button` and `yourValue`. Then you set the button's `onclick` attribute to the function below, so when the button gets clicked, the input's value gets changed to the value of the `yourValue` variable.

```
var input = document.getElementById('text');
var button = document.getElementById('b');
var yourValue = 'Hello World!';

button.onclick = function() {
    input.value = yourValue;
};
```

Comment: but i wanna use it with a constructor because i want to do multiple buttons